# Error while uploading csv to Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, remoteapi

I am trying to upload a csv file to GAE but having errors.
I am following [this](http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/10/using-the-bulkloader-with-java-app-engine/) blog post and using same yml file. I can download data but upload command is giving following errors:

```
C:\Users\ADMIN>appcfg.py upload_data --config_file=C:\bulk\config.yml --file
name=C:\bulk\data.csv --url=http://encryptedsearch.appspot.com/remote_api --appl
ication=encryptedsearch --kind=Greeting
06:44 PM Uploading data records.
[INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20151206.184424
[INFO    ] Throttling transfers:
[INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second
[INFO    ] HTTP connections: 8/second
[INFO    ] Entities inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second
[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10
[INFO    ] Opening database: bulkloader-progress-20151206.184424.sql3
2015-12-06 18:44:24,763 INFO client.py:669 access_token is expired. Now: 2015-12
-06 13:44:24.763000, token_expiry: 2015-12-05 20:24:05
2015-12-06 18:44:25,891 INFO client.py:669 access_token is expired. Now: 2015-12
-06 13:44:25.891000, token_expiry: 2015-12-05 20:24:05
2015-12-06 18:44:26,576 INFO client.py:669 access_token is expired. Now: 2015-12
-06 13:44:26.577000, token_expiry: 2015-12-05 20:24:05
2015-12-06 18:44:27,687 INFO client.py:669 access_token is expired. Now: 2015-12
-06 13:44:27.687000, token_expiry: 2015-12-05 20:24:05
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 133, in
<module>
    run_file(__file__, globals())
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 129, in
run_file
    execfile(_PATHS.script_file(script_name), globals_)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 5469, in <module>
    main(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 5460, in main
    result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 3010, in Run
    self.action(self)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 5116, in __call__
    return method()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4919, in PerformUpload
    run_fn(args)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\ap
pcfg.py", line 4803, in RunBulkloader
    sys.exit(bulkloader.Run(arg_dict, self._GetOAuth2Parameters()))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 4349, in Run
    return _PerformBulkload(arg_dict, oauth2_parameters)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 4211, in _PerformBulkload
    loader.finalize()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\ext\bulk
load\bulkloader_config.py", line 383, in finalize
    self.reserve_keys(self.keys_to_reserve)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\bu
lkloader.py", line 1211, in ReserveKeys
    datastore._GetConnection()._reserve_keys(ConvertKeys(keys))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastor
e\datastore_rpc.py", line 2172, in _reserve_keys
    self._async_reserve_keys(None, keys).get_result()
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastor
e\datastore_rpc.py", line 2210, in _async_reserve_keys
    service_name=_DATASTORE_V4))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastor
e\datastore_rpc.py", line 1341, in _make_rpc_call
    rpc = self._create_rpc(config, service_name)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\datastor
e\datastore_rpc.py", line 1236, in _create_rpc
    rpc = apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC(service_name, deadline, callback)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_stub_map.py", line 414, in __init__
    self.__rpc = CreateRPC(service, stubmap)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\api\apip
roxy_stub_map.py", line 68, in CreateRPC
    assert stub, 'No api proxy found for service "%s"' % service
AssertionError: No api proxy found for service "datastore_v4"
```

I am uploading same file back to datastore which I downloaded with command:

```
appcfg.py download_data --config_file=C:\bulk\config.yml --filename=C:\bulk\data.csv --kind=Greeting --url=http://encryptedsearch.appspot.com/remote_api --application=encryptedsearch
```

**My config.yml is below:**

```
# Autogenerated bulkloader.yaml file.
# You must edit this file before using it. TODO: Remove this line when done.
# At a minimum address the items marked with TODO:
#  * Fill in connector and connector_options
#  * Review the property_map.
#    - Ensure the 'external_name' matches the name of your CSV column,
#      XML tag, etc.
#    - Check that __key__ property is what you want. Its value will become
#      the key name on import, and on export the value will be the Key
#      object.  If you would like automatic key generation on import and
#      omitting the key on export, you can remove the entire __key__
#      property from the property map.

# If you have module(s) with your model classes, add them here. Also
# change the kind properties to model_class.
python_preamble:
- import: base64
- import: re
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.transform
- import: google.appengine.ext.bulkload.bulkloader_wizard
- import: google.appengine.api.datastore
- import: google.appengine.api.users

transformers:

- kind: Greeting
  connector: csv

  connector_options:
    # TODO: Add connector options here--these are specific to each connector.
  property_map:
    - property: __key__
      external_name: key
      import_transform: transform.key_id_or_name_as_string

    - property: content
      external_name: content
      # Type: String Stats: 7 properties of this type in this kind.

    - property: date
      external_name: date
      # Type: Date/Time Stats: 7 properties of this type in this kind.
      import_transform: transform.import_date_time('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
      export_transform: transform.export_date_time('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')

    - property: name
      external_name: name
      # Type: String Stats: 7 properties of this type in this kind.
```

**CSV file contents:**

```
content,date,name,key
Hi,2015-12-05T17:24:14,,ahFzfmVuY3J5cHRlZHNlYXJjaHIrCxIJR3Vlc3Rib29rIgdkZWZhdWx0DAsSCEdyZWV0aW5nGICAgICAgIAKDA
3rd,2015-12-05T17:30:04,,ahFzfmVuY3J5cHRlZHNlYXJjaHIrCxIJR3Vlc3Rib29rIgdkZWZhdWx0DAsSCEdyZWV0aW5nGICAgICA8ogKDA
2nd,2015-12-05T17:25:59,,ahFzfmVuY3J5cHRlZHNlYXJjaHIrCxIJR3Vlc3Rib29rIgdkZWZhdWx0DAsSCEdyZWV0aW5nGICAgICA5JEKDA
```

**Datastore entries:**

[link to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNCaE.png)

Comment: any clue about how to refresh my access token ?

Comment: Is your windows machine in an enterprise environment behind proxy?

Answer (score 2):

For all others that are fighting with the same issue. I found that there was no other solution for me than commenting that line in actual `client.py`.

**Solution:**

- locate the `client.py` file ( `../google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_cloud/lib/oauth2client/oauth2client/client.py` in my case)
- navigate to `access_token_expired()` method
- comment following code:

  ```
  if now >= self.token_expiry:
      logger.info('access_token is expired. Now: %s, token_expiry: %s',
            now, self.token_expiry)
      return True
  ```